# How to load jquery from CDN in a coach view IBM BPM?

Tags: ibm-bpm

This is very basic but I put this code on layout in custom HTML and JQuery doesn't work:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

How do I load resources from the internet on coach view in IBM BPM?  Putting JQuery in to local resources for the project is not an alternative.

Comment: Which error message do you receive? Is there a 404 error during page initialization or is the resource properly loaded?

Comment: resource properly loaded, but the variable $ doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using following steps.

1) Download .js file from above CDN.
2) Import .js file as wen file in your application.
3) Open your coach view --> Go to behaviour tab and you can import above included js in your coach view.